# Python and Sqlite3: Displaying wrong output from database

Tags: python, sqlite

So I'm not getting the correct output and I don't know how to fix this. I have 3 data that goes like this:

| name | num |
| --- | --- |
| Test01 | 2676 |
| Test02 | 2705 |
| Test03 | 2 |

In my code, here's what it is:

```
def check_count():
 conn = sqlite3.connect('registerdb.db')
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM register WHERE num > 183")
 fetch = cursor.fetchall()
 print(fetch)
```

When I run my program, instead of displaying Test01 and Test02 only it also shows the Test03.
I tried changing or adding another data but it still displays the wrong output. Can someone help me please ? Thank you.

If this problem has been solved already, kindly direct me to that link :)

Comment: I suspect that the data type of the column `num` is not INTEGER as it should be.

Comment: Oh ! I see, I'm gonna check it.

Comment: If everything was normal, the query should return the correct rows. That means that either you are querying the wrong database (you do not pass a full path), or the wrong table, or it does not contain the expected values or... For a true [mcve], post the table creation query, the insert that feeds the table, and the query to fetch the data.

Comment: Thank you for the help, It turns out I set it as TEXT instead of INTEGER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you have set the type of the `num` column to a string type, making the comparison lexicographic. Make sure that the `num` column has type `INTEGER` or `REAL` (depending on what you want).

Comment: Now it's fixed. I don't know why I set it as TEXT instead of INTEGER. Thank you !